# How to get outlets inserted in MonoTouch / MonoDevelop / UIBuilder?

Tags: xcode, xamarin.ios, monodevelop

So I have started to play around with MonoTouch.

- OS X 10.6.8
- MonoTouch v4.0.3
- MonoDevelop v2.4.2
- Mono Framework v2.10.2
- XCode v3.2.6

So I'm having problems with the outlets. Creating a simple one page program, editing the XIB in Interface Builder to add outlets, they are properly inserted as class properties into the `MainWindow.xib.designer.cs` like so:

```
[MonoTouch.Foundation.Connect("btnClickMe")]
private MonoTouch.UIKit.UIButton btnClickMe {
    get {
        this.__mt_btnClickMe = ((MonoTouch.UIKit.UIButton)(this.GetNativeField("btnClickMe")));
        return this.__mt_btnClickMe;
    }
    set {
        this.__mt_btnClickMe = value;
        this.SetNativeField("btnClickMe", value);
    }
}
```

However, when I create a multi page navigation based project in MonoDevelop and create outlets for my Views, they are not inserted into the *.designer.xib.cs files.

This is probably some noob beginner mistake, but what could I be doing wrong?

Comment: In which class in Interface Builder are you creating the outlets?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after fiddling around, I found out the issue.
I added my outlets in the `View` class in the Library Windows.
The correct place to add them is in the `File's Owner` class.

@Dimitris, add your comment as an answer, and I can accept it as an answer.